# What is a nice phrase to use instead of "ladies and gentlemen" to be more inclusive?

Tags: teaching, gender, inclusivity

I really like to use the phrase "ladies and gentlemen" while teaching. The reason is not necessarily to be formal, but to gather the attention to a particular point.

For instance, I'd occasionally say "this algorithm, ladies and gentlemen, was only discovered 30 years ago" in order to stress the fact that although the algorithm I am mentioning seems very trivial, people were not able to discover such a way until 30 years ago.

I choose this phrase to occasionally address the students simply because I find it interesting as opposed to "guys" or "folks," both of which are daily language. Also, I came to a realization that these kind of phrases really stimulate the listeners to pay attention even if they lost concentration.

Considering that this phrase might be perceived as a generalization of a group of people, that is there are no non-binary people in the audience, I would like to replace it with a similar toned phrase. Are there any phrases that you know or heard, and think that sounds as cool?

I understand that the question seems off-topic. Please let me clarify. The reason that I am asking this question in Academia.SE is because the phrase I am using considers academic environment, not daily language or some arbitrary presentation. Thus, the potential replacement should be suitable for a classroom. This is why I find it more proper to ask the question here rather than a community where academics are not overwhelmingly populated.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/491617/ladies-and-gentlemen-beyond-binary-gender-classification

Comment: Please don't post answers in the comments, that's what the answer box is for.

Comment: I feel like this is likely to be an evolving question over the next few years. Is there a student group that you could poke the question into? An answer that works here might not work for the specific community around your institution.

Comment: [An airline has addressed the same issue.](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-54336194)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

My favorite podcast, [Good Christian Fun](https://www.goodchristianfun.com/), switched their intro from “ladies and gentlemen” to “friends and folks.”  I think having an “and” in there helps with the rhythm, and feels better than “everybody.”  If friends is weird in class you could try something like “students and scholars”?  I realize these are all a little cheesy, but so is the original phrase, so it’s nice to maintain that tone.

Comment: Some variants using "my": _this algorithm, my friends, was only..._, or _my students_. [I personally use the word 'friends' with care and reservation, but YMMV.]

Comment: I really like the phrase "friends and folks" to be honest! Thank you. I'll definitely give it a try.

Comment: @PabloH Indeed, "my friends" [can be overdone](https://slate.com/culture/2008/09/why-mccain-can-t-stop-saying-my-friends.html).

Comment: Pandits and Padawans!

Answer (score 33):

I just use the word **everybody**.

> Hello everybody.

Or

> This algorithm, everybody, was only discovered...

Suits all cultures, genders and is universal without offending.

(perhaps a question for English Usage SE really)

Comment: this seems like it misses the point of being attention-getting

Comment: This answer will seem so outdated after the incorporeal artificial intelligences take over.  :-P

Answer (score 30):

Actually, most such phrases are little more than a "clearing of the throat" and can be eliminated altogether. They introduce a pause, but little more.

Phrases like "by the way" or "as a matter of fact" or "as is well known" serve the same purpose.

If you really want to draw attention to a point, be more explicit. "It is important/interesting to remember/know/consider that...". This wakes them up a bit, hopefully.

But, "dear students" or similar might work in some cultures.

I once had a colleague who thought of herself as a sort of "mom" to her students and often interspersed "darlings" or "children" in such cases. It was just a personal quirk that worked for her, though it is hard to recommend.

---

The comic in me wants to suggest "slackers" or "you hiding in the back row", but it would be wrong ;-)

Comment: ‘Clearing of the throat’ toss-aways, in the hands of a professional at least, are effective rhetorical techniques to engage. Not to be dismissed without personal consideration.

Comment: Professional vs a belief that 'ladies and gentlemen' *gathers attention to a particular point* ...

Answer (score 19):

Here are some ideas:

- "Ladies and gentlemen and gentlepeople"
- "Gentlefolk"
- "Dear/esteemed students"
- "All ye who attend my class"
- "Friends and folks" or "Students and scholars" (as suggested by @Noah Snyder)
- "People of any and all variety"
- "Thou bunch of remarkable renegades"
- "Esteemed chaotic villains and ne'er-do-wells"
- "Those who are in possession of souls"
- "My delightful crumpets"
- "Academic appreciators"
- "Distinguished personages"
- "Kiddos"
- "Buckaroos"
- "Class-hoppers"

Comment: Most of these are humorous, and could be used them at the start of a speech to break the ice, but if you used them in the middle of a sentence like *"this algorithm, esteemed chaotic villains and ne'er-do-wells, was only discovered 30 years ago"* would draw attention away from the point you're trying to emphasise; all of the listeners would either be laughing at the incongruity, or confused by it.

Comment: If one wanted to go old-school, are the plurals "scolares", "dominae", and "magistrae" gendered?

Comment: @DanielHatton Latin has three grammatical genders (masculine, feminine, neuter), which are associated with gender (the personal characteristic)/animacy in a similar way to in many modern languages. Traditionally the masculine form is considered the 'default', and mixed groups are addressed with the masculine plural. I don't know if any group has adopted norms for inclusive gender-neutral Latin.

Comment: I've encountered people that imitated/parodied some shows, like using "dear audience"; "dear listeners" like a radio show or podcast; "dear viewers" like a TV show; even "dear readers" as if the class is a book or written segment. I found it amusing.

Comment: BTW, anywhere where UK English colloquialisms are commonplace, do not under any circumstances call your students "crumpet".

Comment: @dbmag9 In any case, I remembered as soon as I'd posted that "magistrae" and "dominae" are feminine.

Comment: To grab attention, instead of *"All ye who attend my class"* I might go with *"All ye who wish to pass"*.

Comment: I would love a professor that randomly picked one of these with each instance of use!

Answer (score 15):

Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears.

Comment: I come to bury my academic reputation, not to raise it.

Answer (score 6):

You've said that you want emphasis. How about this?

> This algorithm, was only discovered 30 years ago: now, why do you suppose that was?

**Addendum**: I had forgotten my Shakespeare: he solved the problem in [the Prologue to Henry V](https://shakespeare.folger.edu/shakespeares-works/henry-v/prologue/).

> this algorithm, gentles all, was only discovered 30 years ago

Answer (score 1):

This does not work as a 1-1 replacement for your term in all situations, but I start sentences that I want to emphasize with "Okay people, [...]" which serves a similar purpose.

Answer (score 1):

fellow human beings

fellow contestants in the game of life

fellow travelers on starship Earth

Answer (score 0):

A good answer can be 'Hello There' or 'Hello People'

Comment: General Kenobi! You *are* a bold one.

Comment: This does not seem to fit the attion getting usage.

Comment: "this algorithm, hello there, was only discovered 30 years ago"

Comment: @qwr I think that could work if said in [the right tone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JydZnDuw6w) :P

Comment: As this seems to cause some confusion: [@qwr’s comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/180313/what-is-a-nice-phrase-to-use-instead-of-ladies-and-gentlemen-to-be-more-inclus/180324#comment483953_180324) is aiming at the asker desiring to substitute _ladies and gentlemen_ in a sentence like: “This algorithm, ladies and gentlemen, was only discovered 30 years ago.”

Answer (score -2):

I like the simple

## Listen, All!

It gets attention, and includes, well, all.